# Convert varchar into numeric in SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, varchar, user-defined-types, sql-convert

I'm writing a stored procedure for `INSERT` and I want to convert a `varchar` column into numeric so when I'm writing this code

```
CONVERT(NUMERIC(18,2), CAST([Outcost] AS FLOAT))
```

then it throws this error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CONVERT'.

Here is my query

```
INSERT INTO dbo.UdtEquipmentsStaging
        ([Type], [ModelID], [AccessoryID], [Make], [Model], [Category], 
         [CategoryDescription], [Grouping], [Item], [RequiredModel], [SKU], [ProductNum],
         [Speed], [Description], [Cost], [Cost2], [Cost3], [Cost4], [Cost5], 
         CONVERT(NUMERIC(18,2), CAST([Outcost] AS FLOAT)), [MSRP], 
         [Discontinued], [PercentMSRP], [ServiceType], [ServiceTypeColor],
         [ConnectivityFee], [ConnectFee], [InstallFee], [Notes], [ManufactureNotes]
        , [Special1], [Special2], [Special3], [Special4], [Special5], [Special6], [Special7], [Special8], [Special9], [Special10], [Special11], [Special12], [Special13] 
        , [Special14], [Special15], [Special16], [Special17], [Special18], [Special19], [Special20], [Special21], [Special22], [Special23], [Special24], [Special25] 
        , [Special26], [Special27], [Special28], [Special29], [Special30], [Special31], [Special32], [Special33], [Special34], [Special35], [Special36], [Special37] 
        , [Special38], [Special39], [Special40])
    SELECT 
        [Type], [ModelID], [AccessoryID], [Make], [Model], [Category], 
        [CategoryDescription], [Grouping], [Item], [RequiredModel], [SKU], [ProductNum],
        [Speed], [Description], [Cost], [Cost2], [Cost3], [Cost4], [Cost5], 
        [Outcost], [MSRP], [Discontinued], [PercentMSRP], [ServiceType], [ServiceTypeColor],
        [ConnectivityFee], [ConnectFee], [InstallFee], [Notes], [ManufactureNotes],
        [Special1], [Special2], [Special3], [Special4], [Special5], [Special6], [Special7], [Special8], [Special9], [Special10], [Special11], [Special12], [Special13] 
        , [Special14], [Special15], [Special16], [Special17], [Special18], [Special19], [Special20], [Special21], [Special22], [Special23], [Special24], [Special25] 
        , [Special26], [Special27], [Special28], [Special29], [Special30], [Special31], [Special32], [Special33], [Special34], [Special35], [Special36], [Special37] 
        , [Special38], [Special39], [Special40]
    FROM 
        @Equipments
```

and this is exact error

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure ImportEquipmentFile_UDT, Line 27
>   Incorrect syntax near 'Outcost'.

Comment: Which database platform are you using?

Comment: You should use `CONVERT` in `SELECT` not in list column.

Comment: @DavidLindon Sql server

Comment: @Rokuto So how to convert varchar into numeric at the time of insert.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The column list in the `insert` contains only column names.  The value goes in the `select`:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.UdtEquipmentsStaging
        ( [Type], [ModelID], [AccessoryID], [Make], [Model], [Category], [CategoryDescription], [Grouping], [Item], [RequiredModel], [SKU], [ProductNum]
        , [Speed], [Description], [Cost], [Cost2], [Cost3], [Cost4], [Cost5], [Outcost], [MSRP], [Discontinued], [PercentMSRP], [ServiceType], [ServiceTypeColor]
        , [ConnectivityFee], [ConnectFee], [InstallFee], [Notes], [ManufactureNotes]
        , [Special1], [Special2], [Special3], [Special4], [Special5], [Special6], [Special7], [Special8], [Special9], [Special10], [Special11], [Special12], [Special13] 
        , [Special14], [Special15], [Special16], [Special17], [Special18], [Special19], [Special20], [Special21], [Special22], [Special23], [Special24], [Special25] 
        , [Special26], [Special27], [Special28], [Special29], [Special30], [Special31], [Special32], [Special33], [Special34], [Special35], [Special36], [Special37] 
        , [Special38], [Special39], [Special40])
 SELECT [Type], [ModelID], [AccessoryID], [Make], [Model], [Category], [CategoryDescription], [Grouping], [Item], [RequiredModel], [SKU], [ProductNum]
        , [Speed], [Description], [Cost], [Cost2], [Cost3], [Cost4], [Cost5], CONVERT(NUMERIC(18,2), CAST([Outcost] AS FLOAT)), [MSRP], [Discontinued], [PercentMSRP], [ServiceType], [ServiceTypeColor]
        , [ConnectivityFee], [ConnectFee], [InstallFee], [Notes], [ManufactureNotes]
        , [Special1], [Special2], [Special3], [Special4], [Special5], [Special6], [Special7], [Special8], [Special9], [Special10], [Special11], [Special12], [Special13] 
        , [Special14], [Special15], [Special16], [Special17], [Special18], [Special19], [Special20], [Special21], [Special22], [Special23], [Special24], [Special25] 
        , [Special26], [Special27], [Special28], [Special29], [Special30], [Special31], [Special32], [Special33], [Special34], [Special35], [Special36], [Special37] 
        , [Special38], [Special39], [Special40]
 FROM @Equipments
```